# TCP connection with C on Windows [server/client]

Tags: c, tcp, winsock2, wsastartup

I found that I should use winsock... I tried with this example:

http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/

but error starts with this function `WSAStartup`.

I need client/server connection...

Edit:

I use Windows XP, GCC compiler and Codeblock IDE... I get this error:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FunTool\main.c|15|undefined reference
>   to `WSAStartup@8'|

I am trying to run this code:

```
/*
    Initialise Winsock
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will have to add more details to make this question answerable: what is the error you get, what compiler are you using, what operating system, etc.

Comment: I would prefer that the example was pasted here.  Links can get closed down over time.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And do not just link somewhere. Code has to be included in the text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code compiles and runs fine in Visual Studio 2013.

I am not familiar with the Codeblock IDE, but I suspect it ignores the `pragma` to link with `ws2_32.lib`, causing a linker error.

Based on other SO answers, try opening `project > build options > linker settings` and adding `ws2_32.lib`.

Comment: Where is path for `ws2_32.lib` ?

Comment: It may already be set up in the IDE, so try first without a path. If that does not work, do a search on your computer for the file (the location depends on the SDK version, where it was installed, etc...)

Comment: It doesn't need a path in CodeBlocks, just add ws2_23.lib in link libraries.  Note that #pragma is a compiler-specific directive, as mentioned above gcc doesn't do #pragma comment (lib, "library_name")